# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una lista de 'n' elementos en Python?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, pymysql

Tengo una clase "DataBase" para crear conexiones entre Python y MySQL, y en ella la siguiente función:

```
    def insert(self, tab, columns, values):
    sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(tab, columns, values)

    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise
```

La idea es enviar dos listas, una que contenga las columnas (columns) y otra con los valores (values), pero al ejecutar lo siguiente me da error:

```
    from mysqllizer import DataBase as DB

    conexion = DB("localhost", "root", "", "labrujula")

    columnas = ("id", "nombre", "apellido1", "apellido2", "saldo", "salario", "tipoCliente")
    valores = ('333', 'pepe', 'grillo', 'uchuva', 0, 450000, 'B')

    conexion.insert("clientes", columnas, valores)
```

Me dice que tengo un error de sintaxis y creo que es por las listas. Si alguien sabe cómo solucionarlo o tiene un modo mejor para hacer esto, se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 4):

Estás formateando de forma incorrecta la cadena que representa la petición a la base de datos. Para cada diana de remplazo `{}` se espera una cadena de reemplazo. Si el objeto no es una cadena se llama al método `__str__` (o `__repr__` en su defecto) para obtener la representación en forma de cadena del objeto. Por tanto, al formatear, las tuplas se sustituyen por su representación en forma de cadena, que es algo así:

```
('id', 'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'saldo', 'salario', 'tipoCliente')
```

resultando en una cadena:

```
"INSERT INTO hola (('id', 'nombre', 'apellido1', 'apellido2', 'saldo', 'salario', 'tipoCliente')) VALUES (('333', 'pepe', 'grillo', 'uchuva', 0, 450000, 'B'))"
```

en la cual sobra tanto el paréntesis extra como las comillas.

Por otro lado, **es recomendable parametrizar siempre los valores** en vez de usar formato de cadenas para insertarlos en la petición para prevenir ataques de inyección de código. El nombre de la tabla y las columnas no son parametrizables, aunque los puedes validar previamente a la creación de la query si lo crees necesario por razones de seguridad (mediante lista blanca/lista negra por ejemplo).

El método `str.join` es muy útil para generar las cadenas necesarias a partir de las listas, insertando las comas correspondientes entre cada item:

```
sql = (f"INSERT INTO {tab} ({', '.join(columns)})"
       f"VALUES ({', '.join('?' * len(columns))})")
self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

La cadena quedaría:

```
'INSERT INTO clientes (id, nombre, apellido1, apellido2, saldo, salario, tipoCliente) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
```

Si usas Python < 3.6, sin f-strings (más eficientes y simples), puedes usar `str.format`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO {} ({}) VALUES ({})".format(tab,
                                               ', '.join(columns),
                                               ', '.join('?' * len(columns))
                                               )
self.cursor.execute(sql, values)
```